# Add more levels to expand/collapse jQuery menu

Tags: jquery, menu

I want to use [this expand/collapse jQuery menu](http://perishablepress.com/jquery-accordion-menu-tutorial/#) on my website, but I need to nest more levels. This doesn't seem to be working by just nesting a  to the sub-menu items I want to expand. Has anyone had any luck doing this?

Update: My code so far...

HTML

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='http://google.com'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='http://google.com'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='http://google.com'>Widgets</a></li>
         <li class="has-sub active"><a href='http://google.com'><span>Menus</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='http://google.com'>Widgets</a></li>
               <li><a href='#'>Menus</a></li>
               <li><a href='#'>Products</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href='#'>Products</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Location</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#cssmenu > ul > li:has(ul)').addClass("has-sub");

  $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {
    var checkElement = $(this).next();

    $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');   


    if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
      $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
      checkElement.slideUp('normal');
    }

    if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
      $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
      checkElement.slideDown('normal');
    }

    if (checkElement.is('ul')) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;  
    }       
  });

});
```

Comment: Post the code you try so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57g2nt9t/5/)

Added one more if condition and an extra check in all the others if it has the class `sub-sub-menu`

```
&& (!checkElement.hasClass('sub-sub-menu'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue in the past.  Instead of trying to accomplish all of this with JavaScript, you should be using a CSS 'flyout' menu.  I have a three level menu that I'm using and I think this format will work better for you (it also makes for a cleaner page):

HTML:

```
    <ul>
        <li id="divAdminMenu" runat="server">Admin
            <ul>
                <li>Users
                    <ul>
                        <li class="Page" data-url="<%=Constants.WebPages.User.CREATE_USER %>">Create</li>
                        <li class="Page" data-url="<%=Constants.WebPages.User.EDIT_USER %>">Edit</li>
                        <li class="Page" data-url="<%=Constants.WebPages.User.ASSIGN_ROLES %>">Assign Roles</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Groups
                    <ul>
                        <li class="Page" data-url="<%=Constants.WebPages.Groups.CREATE_GROUP %>">Create</li>
                        <li class="Page" data-url="<%=Constants.WebPages.Groups.ASSIGN_ROLES %>">Assign Roles</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
  </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.menu ul {
font-family:'Comic Sans MS';
z-index:1000;
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}

.menu li{
text-align:center;
color:black;
border:solid 1px black;
border-color:#330000;
background-color:#33EE00;
padding:0;
cursor:pointer;
width:125px;
}

.menu li:hover{
background-color:#FFFF00;
position:relative;
}

.menu ul li{
float:left;
position:relative;
z-index:1000;
}

.menu ul li ul{
position:absolute;
display:none;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul{
left:0;
top:23px;
display:block;
}

.menu ul li ul li{
float:none;
width:125px;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul li ul{
position:absolute;
display:none;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul li:hover ul{
display:block;
left:127px;
top:0;
}
```

As you can see "Admin" is a top-level menu option - once you hover on it, you get 'Users' and 'Groups'  Once you hover on one of those, you get the sub options.  I'm using the 'Page' class so I can use JavaScript to grab the click event - and I'm hiding the URL in the 'data-url' attribute, so that I can redirect them to the next page, but you can use whatever method you prefer.